# Convert String to Decimal Mystery

Tags: c#, .net, string, decimal

I'm facing a problem about the conversion from string to decimal using C# .NET. The problem is that I have wrote the following code and works fine on my development Windows 7 .NET Framework 3.5 system. But, if I move the application on the Windows 2003 Server .NET 3.5 Framework the result is different. Can anyone understand what happen there?

Code:

```
dec = Convert.ToDecimal(strDec);
```

Windows 7    result: 85.00
Windows 2003 result: 8500

Comment: What is the value of `strDec`

Answer (score 24):

It may be that the region and culture settings on your server are set with `,` as decimal, and `.` as digit grouping.  See Control Panel/region and culture settings.

If this numeric string is generated by your application, I would use `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` in both places.

```
     Decimal dec = 85.0m;
     string s = dec.ToString (CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
     decimal.Parse(s, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: The asker didn't say what the input string was, but I suspect this is correct. +1

Answer (score 10):

You are affected by regional settings. When the string 85.00 is parsed in a locale where full stop is used as decimal separator the result is 85.00. If comma is used as decimal separator the result is 8500.

Use the overload where you specify a `CultureInfo`:

```
var dec = Convert.ToDecimal(strDec, CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en"));
```

You can also use `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` which is the default .NET `CultureInfo` and similar to the English `CultureInfo`.

In a production quality application you should always specify or know the `CultureInfo` used when you parse and format strings. If you turn code analysis on in your project you will get warnings when you forget to do that: [CA1304: Specify CultureInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182189.aspx).

Answer (score 4):

Try using culture-ignorant mode

```
var decimalValue = Convert.ToDecimal(stringValue, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: Yes!! That was!!

Thank you!!

Answer (score 4):

We faced with the issue when

```
Convert.ToDecimal("0.5", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

was 0,5

, but

```
Convert.ToDecimal("0,5", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

was 5!

The solution was to use

```
Convert.ToDecimal(stringValue.Replace(",", "."), CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en"));
```

Answer (score 1):

so, i used next function

```
public static Decimal GetInvariantDecimal(string Value)
{
    try
    {
        Decimal d = 0;
        if (Decimal.TryParse(Value, out d))
            return d;
        else
            return Convert.ToDecimal(Value, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

But it only for Russian like decimal separator