# Comma getting removed in dataset after importing data from excel to Dataset

Tags: c#, .net, excel, oledbconnection, import-from-excel

i am using Vs 2008.

We have one functionality where we import excel file,Now excel file can contain numeric data with comma,.However when look at Dataset for same numeric column Commas are getting removed.

I have been using Connection string :

```
string ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" +
            "Data Source=" + "_EXCEL_FILE_NAME_" + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0; IMEX=1; HDR=YES\""
```

i tried all combination of exteneded properties but nothing worked for me.

I have searched on the internet,i have learnt that it is kind of limitation exposed by Microsoft.jet.oledb provider.

Please correct me if i am wrong and provide me a way to get around this problem.

Answer (score 3):

The comma is not actually part of the data - it is only in the representation of the data when presented in excel!!

If you have a field in excel that is numeric data, but you require it to have commas when exported, then you need to convert it to some other type, such as a string using the leading `'` trick.

Answer (score 1):

The trouble is that if you import a decimal that uses a comma as a decimal separator and import it into a system that uses point as the separator, the comma may be is interpreted as a thousands-separator.

Solutions can be found in these SO threads: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6499003/c-sharp-net-convert-string-to-decimal-mystery) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2844810/double-tryparse-input-decimal-separator-different-than-system-decimal-separato).

When importing the data, you might want to explicitly specify the number formats via `NumberStyles` and `CultureInfo`. These are culture specific and, if you do not specify the format, may default to something you did not expect and result in very number values.

Answer (score 0):

To solve this issue, every computer where this is used needs to have the following done:

1. Open Registry Editor
2. Search for TypeGuessRows
3. Change it to 0

You should have no more issues after that...